# Working with Java Wicket WiQuery Selectable

Tags: java, wicket, wiquery

Here's a code using wiquery selectable:

```
    SelectableAjaxBehavior selectableAjaxBehavior = new SelectableAjaxBehavior() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public void onSelection(Component[] components, AjaxRequestTarget     ajaxRequestTarget) {
            System.out.println("SIZE: " + components.length);
        }
    };
    selectableAjaxBehavior.getSelectableBehavior().setSelectedEvent(new JsScopeUiEvent() {
        @Override
        protected void execute(JsScopeContext scopeContext) {
            scopeContext.append("console.log('ID: ' + ui.selected.id);");
        }
    });
    selectableAjaxBehavior.setFilter(".tooth-image");
    add(selectableAjaxBehavior);
```

I'm trying to use this on images in a class: "tooth-image". When I select some images from the method "onSelection()", I get an empty array of selected components. When triggering select action I see elements' IDs in the browser's console, so it works.

So, maybe someone knows what I have do to stop getting an empty array of selected components ?